# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object occurring with grayscale file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel, grayscale

I want to convert a file to grayscale in python using PIL and then get the x,y and rgb value of the pixels but I am getting an error.

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
file_name = "test.png"
og_image = Image.open(file_name)
gray_image = ImageOps.grayscale(og_image)
gray_scalefile = f"{file_name[:-3]}gray.png"
gray_image.save(gray_scalefile)
img = Image.open(gray_scalefile)
pixels = img.load() 
width, height = img.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
        print(x, y, f"{r},{g},{b}")
```

contents of text.png:
[image]

contents of text.gray.png:
[image]

The code works fine with the text.png but when I grayscale it just doesn't work and gives me this error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Image Manipulation\Image Manipulation.py", line 12, in <module>
    r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_name = "test.jpg"
og_image = Image.open(file_name)
gray_image = ImageOps.grayscale(og_image)
gray_scalefile = f"{file_name[:-3]}gray.jpg"
gray_image.save(gray_scalefile)
img = Image.open(gray_scalefile).convert('RGB')
pixels = img.load()
width, height = img.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r,g,b= pixels[x, y]
        print(x, y, f'{r},{g},{b}')
```

This will work, cause it converts Luminescence to rgb first

Comment: the code suggested here is solving the initial issue by converting the gray scale to an RGB. the 
gray scale file can output like: ````x=163 y=109  156````, the final converted RGB can output: 
````x=163 y=109  156, 156, 156```` which has now 3 planes / channels, but they are all indentical, 
and 2 of them are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

i just wanted to raise some doubts about the initial post:

the error message `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object` indicates, that  the line:
`r, g, b = pixels[x, y]` is not returning 3 values (as RGB), but just one value. this is because
a gray scale image does have only one plane / channel. to solve this issue we can use this: `value = pixels[x, y]`

here is my suggestion:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("test_rgb.png").convert("L")
img.save("test_gray_scale.png")
pixels = img.load()
for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        value = pixels[x, y]
        print(f'{x=} {y=}  {value}')
img.close() # don't forget to close the image object
```

Comment: The reason why I added the conversion to rgb is because the original script mentioned ```r,g,b =pixels[x, y]```, but your answer is great when it comes to single channel.(grayscale)